# Simplicial and De Rham Homology on Manifolds

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex, de-rham-cohomology

I'm looking for a recomendable reference/source for a rigorous proof that for manifolds (with "nice enough" structure) the ***simlicial*** and ***De Rham (co)homologies*** coincide.

Especially, I know that there exist criterions from axiomatic (co)homology theories which provide a statement about different (co)homology theories just if the neccessary conditions are fullfilled.

But I'm looking preferably for a reference where a concrete isomorphism between both (co)homologies above is constructed. So with viewpoint to geometric intuition.

Comment: I do not know for DeRahm homology, but you can see on "Lectures on algebraic topology" from Matveev, there is a section (1.11) that presents an axiomatic approach that guaranty that all homology verifying those axioms are isomorphic.

Comment: I think your problem might be that there are smooth manifolds without a simplicial structure.

Comment: @Randall: this reflects my vague formulation "...with "nice enough" structure...". So we can for example assume that considered manifolds have simplicial structure

Comment: My guess is that would be tough, because you need those "nice enough" structures to be stable enough for excision, M-V, etc.

Comment: @Randall - It is a theorem of Cairns (and Whitehead, 1940's) that every smooth manifold admits a compatible simplicial structure.

Answer (score 1):

In Bott and Tu (Differential forms in algebraic topology) there are proofs that both de Rham cohomology and singular cohomology agree with Čech cohomology (with respect to a good cover).  In Hatcher (Algebraic topology) you can find a proof that singular and simplical cohomology agree.

Note that the first half of the above (the isomorphism between de Rham and singular cohomology) is often called [de Rham's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#De_Rham%27s_theorem).